# Synchronization between @async methods

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have to sychronize between asynchronous methods.

I have got three methods say

method1, method2, method3 with the following defenitions

```
void method1() {
    method2();
    //some code
    method3();
}

@Async
void method2() {
    //some code
}


@Async
void method3() {
    //some code
}
```

My requirement is that I want to make sure that method3 is executed after method2. After doing some search I have come to a conclusion to use a new SimpleThreadPoolTaskExecutor with pool size configured to 1 and use it for the methods method2 and method3. I would like to know whether there is any better option than this. I am new to Spring Task scheduling. And sorry for not providing a demoable example.

Comment: A thread pool with size 1 basically disabled async processing ...

Comment: I don't have frequent access to the internet. So please expect some delay.Thats the basic intention. Synchronization between required methods. i will just mention the @Async(value="myexecuter") for method2 and method3. The rest async methods will be executed with default task executer.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. If these really need to be ordered, their jobs shouldn't be fired all at once; `method3` shouldn't be scheduled until `method2` is already finished.

Comment: Why do you want `@Async` if they aren't really `@Async`? Just make method1 `@Async`...

Comment: `method2` and `method3 `should be async w.r.t `method1` which is my actual execution.

Comment: @M.Deinum Also annotating `method1` with `@Async` won't ensure synchronization between `method2` and `method3`

Comment: Not ALSO instead of.... IMHO there is no point (from your code) in annotating those methods with `@ASync` you want them to be processed synchronously ...

Answer (score 1):

```
void method1() {
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    semaphore.aquire();
    method2(semaphore);
    method3(semaphore);
}


@Async
void method2(Semaphore semaphore) {
   //do some stuff
   semaphore.release();
}

@Async
void method3(Semaphore semaphore) {
    semaphore.aquire();

    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will off course think of this approach if nothing else works. But I will try my best to stick to the spring task executor.